# Can't get listed of selected items from multiselect ListBox in Excel userform

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

New to VBA and having some difficulty getting selected items from a ListBox. I keep getting an error on the For line.  The name of the ListBox is correct and I think .ListCount should work.

```
Sub GetListBox1()
Dim SelectedItems As String

For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If ListBox1.Selected = True Then
    SelectedItems = SelectedItems & ListBox1.List(i)
    End If
Next i

Debug.Print SelectedItems

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is this code `Sub GetListBox1` located ? is it inside the `User_form` module ? what function or control triggers it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code below, switch `"UserForm1"` with the name of your form.

```
Dim SelectedItems As String

With UserForm1 ' replace with the name of your form
    For i = 0 To .ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If .ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then  ' <-- you need to add the index of the selected item (according to the loop)
            SelectedItems = SelectedItems & .ListBox1.List(i)
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Thanks that was great!  Besides missing that i I also had it in a module rather than the Userform

Comment: I can't get the count of selected items though.  I need to put commas between them but not the last one.  This is what I have but I'm getting an "argument not optional" error on `.ListBox1.Selected.ListCount`.  Is that the wrong syntax?

Comment: @bigbucky I don't have anywhere in my code `.ListBox1.Selected.ListCount` , where did you get this part from ?

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t very clear. Your code worked great. I was trying to adjust it to get the values separated by commas but couldn’t figure it out. See below.

Answer (score 1):

To Add commas in your output, try this...

```
Dim SelectedItems As String

With UserForm1 ' replace with the name of your form
    For i = 0 To .ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If .ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then  ' <-- you need to add the index of the selected item (according to the loop)
            SelectedItems = SelectedItems & .ListBox1.List(i) & ", " ' <-- THE COMMA goes here 
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

The way you did it in a ELSE clause would only add a comma if the listbox item was NOT selected, and WOULD add a comma for every listbox item that wasn't selected.

So If a user selected Alabama, and Montana from the states listbox choices, the output would show the two state names, plus 48 commas.

Comment: Thanks it took me a while but I eventually figured that out.  Then I just subtracted two characters from the string so I didn't have an extra comma at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sai Rado that worked. Trying to get them separated by commas but can’t get it to work.

```
Sub GetListBox1()
Dim SelectedItems As String
Dim SelectedCounter As Integer
SelectedCounter = 0

With UserForm1
    For i = 0 To .ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If .ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
            SelectedCounter = SelectedCounter + 1
                If SelectedCounter = .ListBox1.Selected.ListCount Then
                    SelectedItems = SelectedItems & .ListBox1.List(i)
                Else
                    SelectedItems = SelectedItems & .ListBox1.List(i) & ", "
        End If
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```