# Getting Selections of Multiselect ListView on VBA UserForm

Tags: vba, listview

[listview sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl5Ds.png)I am using a listview on a user form. I have multi-select enabled. I would like to select multiple items in the listview and then take the value found in some other text boxes on the same form and push those values into the selected items subitems (columns). The listview is somewhat of a new beast to me. I have the listview filling without issue. I am able to push data to a single selected row, but I am at a loss on how to get all the selected rows indexes and then push to all the subitems accordingly. I end up only getting the last selected row.

Thx.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `push those values into the selected items subitems (columns)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get listed of selected items from multiselect ListBox in Excel userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47195174/cant-get-listed-of-selected-items-from-multiselect-listbox-in-excel-userform)

Comment: I can use this to write the values to the listview:  ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(7) = SparesQty.Text .  I am using a listview not listbox.

Answer (score 0):

To Get The selected Items, use the code :

```
ListeCount = myListview.ListItems.Count
For i = 1 To ListeCount
        If myListview.ListItems.Item(i).Selected Then
        MsgBox myListview.ListItems.Item(i).Text
    End If
Next i
```

EDIT #1 :

```
ListeCount = myListview.ListItems.Count
For i = 1 To ListeCount
    If myListview.ListItems.Item(i).Checked Then
            MsgBox myListview.ListItems.Item(i).Text
            'Check if The column 2 of item 'i' is empty
            If myListview.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(1) = vbNullString Then
                'Fill the empty column with a value
                myListview.ListItems.Item(i).SubItems(1) = "Test"
            End If
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: MsgBox is coming back empty - no values

Comment: check if your listview is filled with data ? and did you change the 'myListview' with your listview name ?

Comment: Listview is definitely filled and I changed the code to match my controls names.

Comment: first column is a check box, would that matter?

Comment: Strange ! Where did you put the code ? did you put it in a Command Button Click event ?

Comment: I think I have it -ListView1.SelectedItem.SubItems(i) gives me back the row data now All I need to do is step through rows. I will report back ASAP.

Comment: so I have added link to an image in the original post of what I need to do. All I get back for the above code is the last row selected in the listview

Comment: If you are selecting with checking the checkboxes, Changing the 'ListView1.ListItems.Item(i).Selected' to 'ListView1.ListItems.Item(i).Checked' in The above code will resolve your problem ..

Comment: I want the user to be able to add the selected text in the listboxes below the listview to the empty cells in the listview and then later when finished processing have only the check boxed items acted upon, hence the reason for multi-select and checkboxes. So the multi select is for the text updates and the check box is for the fial processing.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't check the picture, because of security problem at work .. It shows access denied .. I edited my answer so that you can change a value of a column in your listview , Check it .. Hope it helps ..